# IBM DB2 Content Manager System Administrator 8.2.Export objects

Tags: db2-content-manager

I´m migrating from IBM Content Manager 8.2. to 8.4.
so I need to export objects like data type items, worklists, process, etc from one version to another, on Content Manager System Administrator 8.4.

8.4.3 lets me do right-click and export, but how to export from 8.2?
I wish you can help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at our Product CMAdmin:

http://die-archivisten.de/loesungen/loesungen-fuer-ibm-content-manager/cmadmin/

Information only in german at the Moment

Best Regards,
Ralf